# How to efficiently map query results to parameters using JDBI?

Tags: java, jdbi

I have a case where I am constructing an Object through a series of queries. For optimiziation, the construction of Objects are batched together, the queries use `IN` clauses to allow processing of a batch of Objects.

In the below example, given a list of `MyObject`, I would like to populate `MyObject.c` based on the values of `MyObject.a` and `MyObject.b`. Using the skife.jdbi libraries, my implementation for this looks something like the below.

Any suggestions for improvements?

It might be more efficient if I parsed the raw result set (though I can't find how to get my interface to do mapping of the result set)?

Or it would be much more more tidy if there were some way to directly map the query paramaters to results (but I haven't been able to find a way)?

```
class MyObject {
String a;
String b;
String c;

// ....

String z;

}

void populateC(Set<MyObject> objects) {
  // parse the list, populating Lists which will be used for the query and a 
  // Map which will be used to map query results back to the MyObjects in the Set param

  Map<PopulateCQuerydata, MyObject> queryDataToParamMap = new HashMap<>;
  List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>;
  List<String> bList = new ArrayList<>;


  for (MyObject object : objects) {
     queryDataToParamMap.put(new CResult(object), object);
     aList.add(object.a);
     bList.add(object.b);
  }  


  Set<CResult> results = dao.getC(aList, bList);

  for (CResult result : results) {
    queryDataToParamMap.get(result).c = result.c;
  }

}

@RegisterMapper(CResultMapper.class)
@UseStringTemplate3StatementLocator("/sql/PopulateCDao.sql.stg")
interface PopulateCDao {
  @SqlQuery
  List<CResults> getC(@BindIn("aList") List<String> a, @BindIn("bList") List<String> b);
}

class CResults {
  String a;
  String b;
  String c;

  CResults(MyObject object) {
    a = object.a;
    b = object.b;
  }

// implement these so this type can be used in the HashMap
  @Override
 public boolean equals(Object other) {
   if (this == other) {
     return true;
   } else if (!(other instanceof CResults )) {
        return false;
   } else {
      CResults otherQueryData = (CResults)other;
        return a.equals(otherQueryData.a) && b.equals(otherQueryData.b);
    }
   }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      int hash = 1;
      hash = hash * 31 + a.hashCode() + b.hashCode();
      return hash;
    }

}

public class CResultMapper implements ResultSetMapper<CResult> {

  @Override
  public CResult map(int index, ResultSet resultSet, StatementContext statementContext) throws SQLException  {

    CResult result = new CResult();
    result.a = resultSet.getInt("a");
    result.b = resultSet.getInt("b");
    result.c = resultSet.getInt("c");

    return result;
  }
}

//sql/PopulateCDao.sql.stg

group PopulateCDao;

getC(aList, bList) ::= <<
    SELECT a, b, c FROM tblJoinC WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE a IN (<aList>) AND b IN (<bList>)
>>
```